# Why is "plummet", as an intransitive verb, followed by a noun?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, verbs

> Consumer confidence plummeted **a breathtaking 15 points**, to its lowest level in ten years.

> The cable just snapped. The elevator plummeted **ten flights**.

> Stock prices plummeted **40 percent** during the scandal.

What grammatic role do the bolded nouns play in the sentence?

Comment: These are not objects. They're all measure phrases. Notice that they can't be passivized, like real objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They function adverbially. (Terminology will vary.) It is very common for nominal phrases to modify verbs this way (!), and neither the word "plummet" nor numbers need to be involved:

> Consumer confidence rose **Monday**.
> The elevator shook **a great deal**.
> Stock prices have risen **many times** since the last recession.